# Que diferencia y beneficio tiene un array contra el listarray

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Hola soy programador java y estoy viendo algunos que dicen que es mejor `ArrayList` que un `Array` normal?

Yo honestamente no veo diferencia yo lo veo igual

Comment: Cada situación tiene una tecnologia mas apropiada que otra. No es que uno sea mejor que otro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Un ArrayList tiene un tamaño dinámico, mientras que el de un Array es
  definido en su creación.
- Un ArrayList no puede contener datos
  primitivos, sólo Objetos.
- El ArrayList permite comprobar que los
  datos que se añaden a la colección son del tipo correcto en tiempo de
  compilación.
- El Array puede ser de varias dimensiones, el ArrayList
  es unidimensional (aunque pueda ser un ArrayList de ArrayLists).

Answer (score 2):

Hola asi como indican en la respuesta anterior un ArrayList puede cambiar de tamaño segun se necesite en tiempo de ejecucion , la Clase ArrayList implementa la interfaz List

```
List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

El valor Integer entre el operador diamante ( < > ) indica el tipo de objeto que debe ingresar puesto que si intentas realizar esto : `lista.add("1");` no compilara ya que el pide un Integer ( 1,2,3...)  y se esta intentando enviar un String.

Saludos.